# Triggering driver module rebuild on kernel update

Tags: drivers, upgrade, kernel, modules

I'm using hardware that requires a driver to be built which is not present in the kernel source tree, i.e. not "part of" linux.  Currently I'm finding it necessary to rebuild and install the driver manually every time I start using a new kernel version.  Is there a way to streamline this process?

Answer (score 5):

For automatically recompiling kernel modules after a kernel update, i know of two options:

1. write your own script

   For inspiration i refer to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=835573) very old post or [this](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/development/programming-scripting/448260-automatically-recompile-kernel-modules-after-kernel-update.html) one
   where some one solved it for SUSE by a script
2. Use Dynamic Kernel Module Suppor (DKMS)

   I refer to short description [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) page and ubuntu community page HOWTO for [DKMS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS)