# Ethernet not working well in Ubuntu 18.04 on new desktop

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, realtek

Assembled a developer (non gaming) desktop with following configuration:

- Processor: Intel i5 8400
- Memory: DDR4-2400 8GB (double-rank), 1.2V, CL17
- Motherboard: MSI H310M PRO-VH
- HDD: Seagate Barracuda 1TB 7200rpm SATA

Then I installed Ubuntu 18.04 from the latest downloaded ISO image, via a pendrive. After connecting the desktop via the onboard LAN interface, to my home router, the interface goes into, a log **Connecting** state, never manages to actually connect, and finally becomes **Disconnected**. This is when the Wired ethernet is configured with defaults to use DHCP. Here is what `ip a` shows:

```
xyz@shivalik:~$ ip a
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:9c:23:b3:cd:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::452c:f71e:f47d:1b54/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If I modify the Wired Ethernet interface to use static-IP, the interface seems to come up, but not work. I am unable to reach even the home router, that is at the other end of the ethernet cable connected to the Desktop. In this case, here is what `ip a` shows:

```
xyz@shivalik:~$ ip -s a
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:9c:23:b3:cd:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.220/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::452c:f71e:f47d:1b54/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    0          0        0       0       0       0       
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    1624       35       0       0       0       0
```

The motherboard documentation says that it has the **Realtek RTL8111H Gigabit LAN controller** on board. Here some of the troubleshooting information I've gathered on this host:

```
xyz@shivalik:~$ lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:7b33]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

and

```
xyz@shivalik:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: 30:9c:23:b3:cd:42
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:123 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1104000-a1104fff memory:a1100000-a1103fff
```

Have replaced the LAN cables (with brand new spare ones I had), but that didn't change anything. The LAN port LEDs indicate PHY connectivity it seems, on both end and they are blinking, albeit slowly. What do I have to do to get the network working on this desktop ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is available at [this off-SO link](https://unixblogger.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/).

In summary, here is what I did that solved the issue.

1. Inserted a WiFi USB dongle and connected to the WiFi router, and tested that internet connection is working.
2. Did: `sudo apt-get update`
3. Did: `sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms` to install the r8168 kernel driver (suppressing the r8169 driver that came default with the kernel)
4. Reboot the PC
5. After reboot the Wired Ethernet started working.

Comment: this apparently worked for me, although for some reason it only took effect after I reinstall the kernel (linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic). I tried restarting several times and manually loading thru `modprobe` but only reinstalling seems to take effect.

Comment: The r8168 driver is a DKMS driver, so the observation is somewhat strange. You see why so in this [Ask-Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111177/triggering-driver-module-rebuild-on-kernel-update) answer.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I should have said _"but only reinstalling it seems to have taken effect in my case"_. That was an unexpected behavior for me also... I was having other problems with my sound card, but none related specific to drivers tho...

Comment: Thanks @bdutta74  unfortunately it did not seem to work for my issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277732/getting-make-build-essential-and-ethernet-drivers-installed-on-ubuntu-18-04-ma

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some more investigation on that.
Here are some things that can be tested.

- connect a definitive working device on that cable/router-interface, to check that cable and router-interface are working
- use a live-distro like kali linux or something similar that will boot from pendrive, to check that your hardware is ok
- check if the correct modules are loaded for the ethernet controller

Comment: Thanks. For point #1 - confirmed that router and cables are fine by using my laptop and connecting using them. For point #2 - I've used Lubuntu 18.04 live via pen-drive, with exactly same effect. Wondering, why would it be any better using Kali linux live-distro ? Is Kali known to have wider range-of, more recent drivers ? Checking around I notice that r8169 is most commonly used module for RTL8111H device, although I found some about recommendation to use r8168 module (like this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/558944/is-r8168-installer-in-ubuntu-software-center-secure-and-working?rq=1).

Comment: Kali is only an example. But because it is highly network related, it may have a better support for network interfaces - just a guess.  Maybe you like to use it for doublechecking. If this also fails, I assume that your onboard LAN is defektive. I have no experience with the RTL8111H device but my personal experience in networking shows that sometimes hardware incompatibilities prevent some NICs form connecting to a specific network device.

Answer (score 0):

I did follow the `r8168-dkms` install answer, but what fixed the issue for me was: Cleaning the Ethernet port!