# Please help to swith on ethernet on my HP laptop

Tags: 20.04, ethernet, hp

I have HP Pavilion - 15-cs3073cl, officially there are no Linux drivers on HP website
I have installed Ubuntu 20.04
WiFi is working fine but Ethernet not
I have also Windows 10 installed on this laptop and under the Windows Ethernet is working also.
Here is the result of command "sudo lshw -C network":

```
...
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical ID: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(размер=256) память:51004000-51004fff память:51000000-51003fff
```

There is no option to swith on Ethernet or create a new connection in the setting page

[Ethernet setting page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5TMd.png)

I'm not good in Linux, could anyone help me in this question?

ifconfig

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 866  bytes 75738 (75.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 866  bytes 75738 (75.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.105  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe70::c8f6:ef26:54cc:4ef  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 6c:46:2a:ec:4e:21  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5868  bytes 2778399 (2.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5642  bytes 1122951 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

sudo service networking status

```
etworking.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit networking.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2020-10-08 22:11:28 +03; 28min ago
   Main PID: 855 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

окт 08 22:03:38 Workpc systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
окт 08 22:03:38 Workpc systemd[1]: Finished Raise network interfaces.
окт 08 22:11:28 Workpc systemd[1]: Stopping Raise network interfaces...
окт 08 22:11:28 Workpc systemd[1]: networking.service: Succeeded.
окт 08 22:11:28 Workpc systemd[1]: Stopped Raise network interfaces.
```

sudo service network-manager status

```
etworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-10-08 22:28:27 +03; 13min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 9577 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18884)
     Memory: 6.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─9577 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

окт 08 22:28:31 Workpc NetworkManager[9577]: <info>  [1602185311.8588] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed unknown -> bound
окт 08 22:28:31 Workpc NetworkManager[9577]: <info>  [1602185311.8611] device (wlo1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
окт 08 22:28:31 Workpc NetworkManager[9577]: <info>  [1602185311.8646] device (wlo1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed>
окт 08 22:28:31 Workpc NetworkManager[9577]: <info>  [1602185311.8650] device (wlo1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'manage>
окт 08 22:28:31 Workpc NetworkManager[9577]: <info>  [1602185311.8655] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
окт 08 22:28:31 Workpc NetworkManager[9577]: <info>  [1602185311.8674] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
окт 08 22:28:31 Workpc NetworkManager[9577]: <info>  [1602185311.8675] policy: set 'Bruce Lee ' (wlo1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
окт 08 22:28:31 Workpc NetworkManager[9577]: <info>  [1602185311.8681] device (wlo1): Activation: successful, device activated.
окт 08 22:28:31 Workpc NetworkManager[9577]: <info>  [1602185311.8689] manager: startup complete
окт 08 22:28:32 Workpc NetworkManager[9577]: <info>  [1602185312.3301] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto dsl-provider
#iface dsl-provider inet ppp
#pre-up /bin/ip link set eno1 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
#provider dsl-provider

#auto eno1
#iface eno1 inet manual
```

Comment: How is ethernet not working,  is it - like not at all- responding to internet?  (not flashing, not connecting, not anything like that?)    Welcome to Askubuntu by the way!

Comment: In the settings there are no option to setup any ethernet connectionm, only VPN

Comment: Hmm, wifi works right?  if wifi works: and if you have the same driver as this one:   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043384/ethernet-not-working-well-in-ubuntu-18-04-on-new-desktop?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you William, but when i tried to install drier it says that already exist
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
r8168-dkms is already the newest version (8.048.00-1).
Main problem i think what when i run "sudo lshw -C network" there is no Local name for my device so i cun't een turn it manually on
BY the way WiFi workin fine

Comment: Okay,  can you try to: provide us the output of ifconfig, and can you try sudo service networking status and  sudo service network-manager status  and also;  if it would be the local name, we can just sudo hostname <yournewhostname>  And,  a bit much here but:   can you provide the contents of this file too?  /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: I updated the question wuth requested information. Also file etc/network/interfaces was modified before by me and i comment all changes - no result

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8168` ? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: sudo modprobe r8168
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8168': Operation not permitted

Comment: Is Secure Boot enabled in the EFI/BIOS? It probably should be disabled.

Comment: Yes after Disabling the Secure Boot and rebooting it asked me to configure 8168 i select Yes and now all are working fine. Thank you @chili555

Answer (score 2):

After Disabling the Secure Boot in the BIOS and rebooting it asked me to configure 8168 I select Yes and now all are working fine.
Also I switch on Network Boot in the BIOS, maybe that was also a reason. But then not clear why in Windows all was fine.